# How to extract fixed factors after equation term shift?

Tags: equation-solving

The equation given is:

```
y - y1 == (y1 - y2)/(1 - x2) (x - 1)
```

How to transfer y1 to the right side of the equation and extract the common factor (y1 y2)/(1 x2) to obtain this result?

```
y == (y1 - y2)/(1 - x2) (x - 1 + (y1 (1 - x2))/(y1 - y2))
```

I tried the following method myself but failed to achieve my goal

```
linAQ = y - y1 == (y1 - y2)/(1 - x2) (x - 1)
linAQ /. 
 y - a_ == (y1 - y2)/(1 - x2) (x - b_) :> 
  y == (y1 - y2)/(1 - x2) (x - c)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(y/.First@Solve[y-y1==(y1-y2)/(1-x2) (x-1),y])/((y1-y2)/(1-x2))//Apart
```

---

```
-1 + x + (-y1 + x2 y1)/(-y1 + y2)
```

Which is same as yours `(x - 1 + (y1 (1 - x2))/(y1 - y2))`.